# pg_restore from sql workbench shows -U syntax error with DB indentifier

Tags: postgresql, pg-restore

`pg_restore -U (Aw Master username)` returns syntax -U error.

What username am I supposed to use?

Answer (score 0):

*pg_restore is a utility for restoring a PostgreSQL database from an archive created by pg_dump.*

It cannot be used inside SQL Workbench.

Try in command Dir/Shell.

[Reference](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgrestore.html)